# How aliases are available in the main shell, but not in the subshell?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell

I was reading some text and it states:

> The .bashrc shell configuration file is actually executed each time
>   you generate a BASH shell, such as when you run a shell script. In
>   other words, each time a subshell is created, the .bashrc file is
>   executed. This has the effect of exporting any local variables or
>   aliases you have defined in the .bashrc shell initialization file.

I also read that each time I execute a shell script (say **script1.sh**), a subshell is created. So when this subshell is created, **.bashrc** file must execute and thus alias(es) defined in **.bashrc** must be available in the subshell (which are not). And if alias(es) are not available in this subshell, then how are they available in the main shell(via which i execute my script)?

Comment: You need to have an **`interactive shell/subshell`** in order to execute aliases defined in `.bashrc`

Comment: Also doing a `man bash` will show you that *" Aliases  are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below). "*

Comment: [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) answers all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Right, in linux' bash shell you can say

```
source /path/to/my_lib.sh
```

for loading your alias defs from file. Or, for lowering complexity, you can simply copy that alias defs in your bash script.

But wait! This will only create the aliases , probably with

```
alias foo3 foo9  # describe these two aliases: declare errors if one doesn't exist
```

you will enjoy your new alias defs but running them is going to fail before you enable alias expansion with:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases # alias xpn ON
```

Consider also:

```
shopt -u expand_aliases # alias xpn OFF
```

or

```
shopt  expand_aliases   # query whether
```

or

```
unalias foo3 foo9 # delete these aliases
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined aliases in `script1.sh` and you want them to be available everywhere, add to your `.bashrc` file:

`source /path/to/script1.sh`

or alternatively:

`. /path/to/script1.sh`

To avoid an error in case the script does not exist, you can use:

`if [ -f /path/to/script1.sh ]; then source /path/to/script1.sh; fi`

The same works for any functions you define in `script1.sh`.